# hook_theme_suggestions_page() provide default template file inside module folder

Tags: theming, 8

I am using hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK() to implement a custom template file in my drupal 8 website like below.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables) {
  $template_suggestions = array();
  // This is used to display only $content.
  if (isset($_GET['ajax']) && $_GET['ajax'] == 1) {
    $template_suggestions[] = 'page__ajax';
  }
  return $template_suggestions;
}
```

Above code is working fine and I can add template page--ajax.html.twig inside my current active theme and changes in template is reflecting in page.

But when I put that file inside my module itself file is not detecting and changes not reflecting in page and taking default page.html.twg template file.

How can I provide default template file within my module itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue got resolved by adding `hook_theme()`. Normally theme suggestion templates are only picked up when they are in themes. So We need explicitly define theme suggestions using `hook_theme()` inside a module. Then only it takes templeate from your modules templates folder.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'page__ajax' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'base hook' => 'page',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You should specifiy 'base hook', see system_theme(). Otherwise some things will not run they way they do with a normal template override.

Comment: which is `base hook` for page template? html?

Comment: no, that is not what base hook means. It is just 'page'.

Comment: I updated in answer. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct to me.