# Is it possible with one of the template suggestion hooks to also specify a new template location?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

In a custom module I'm adding a custom page template suggestion per multi-site like following which would then search for `page--MYSITE.html.twig` in the current theme's `/templates` folder.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $site_path = \Drupal::service('site.path');
  $site_path = explode('/', $site_path);
  $site_name = $site_path[1];

  $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $site_name;
}
```

**Question**: Is it possible to also specify a new location for this template. Like let's say inside my custom module's `/templates` folder?

**Why**: It would let me use a core theme but with my custom template (without the need to add something custom to core or to create a new sub-theme, lazy as I am).

There are 3 suggestion hooks that come into my mind but with none if them it seems possible to also specify a custom location. Is this right? Or is there a way? Is it bad practice to do so?

- [`hook_theme_suggestions_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x)
- [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x)
- [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8.2.x)

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible with one of the template suggestion hooks to also specify a new template location?*

You can specify a new template location in [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.5.x):

> **path**: Override the path of the file to be used. Ordinarily the module or theme path will be used, but if the file will not be in the
>   default path, include it here. This path should be relative to the
>   Drupal root directory.

---

> *Like let's say inside my custom module's /templates folder?*

This means when using hook_theme() instead of hook__theme_suggestions_* the module's template folder is already default and you don't need to specify `path`.

So you can use this answer  [hook_theme_suggestions_page() provide default template file inside module folder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207640/hook-theme-suggestions-page-provide-default-template-file-inside-module-folder).

Comment: Ah I see, per `base hook` override. Thanks for the linked answer! I guess that makes my question a duplicate then :)

Comment: Your question is broader for how to specify a new template location (which could be any path), so I answered this part and then referenced the existing question.